# How can I make a camera application using flutter desktop?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-plugin, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

I want to make a custom camera application using the flutter desktop but unfortunately I'm not able to find any suitable plugin for that. Is there a way to make a custom **plugin** that would help me access the camera of my computer?

Comment: you can use official plugin <camera_windows>